# collectionViewCell : error while unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, runtime-error

I created a collection view for which I want the cell to show two labels ("product" and "price"). The titles of the labels will be based on an array (a list of products).

So I have a UIViewController class in which is my collection view code and a UICollectionViewCell class in which is a function with this code :

```
class ShoppingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var produitLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var prixLabel: UILabel!
    


    func manageLabel(with produitName: String)  {
          
        produitLabel.text = produitName
          
    
          
        
      }
    

}
```

And in my CollectionViewController here is my code :

```
class ShoppingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // IBoutlet
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    

    
    // IB action
    //
    
    
    var typeOfProducts = ProduitsStr.init(products: ["bananes","pommes"])
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        
    }
    

    
}
```

```
extension ShoppingViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
  
    
    
}
```

```
extension ShoppingViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return typeOfProducts.products.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
        let cell = ShoppingCollectionViewCell()
       
        
        if let produitCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ShoppingCollectionViewCell {
        
            produitCell.manageLabel(with: typeOfProducts.products[indexPath.row])
            
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
}
```

The problem is that when I run the app I've got this error :

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/_/Desktop/developppemnt application/Project FoodApp_v4/Project FoodApp_v4/controller/ShoppingCollectionViewCell.swift, line 23 2020-10-09 17:26:56.600385+0200 Project FoodApp_v4[18353:106284] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/_/Desktop/developppemnt application/Project FoodApp_v4/Project FoodApp_v4/controller/ShoppingCollectionViewCell.swift, line 23`

I don't understand why I got this issue, could anyone give me a helping hand ?

Thanks !

Comment: For starters, you are returning a newly created cell (variable named `cell`), not the dequeued one (variable named `produitCell`). Fix your code to return the dequeued cell and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli I trie but its the same problem. Basically what I'd like is to have a label inside my collection view cell and the text of the label to change based on values stored in an array, but i don't see how I could do it ...

Comment: Thank you, please correct that in the question. Bummed that didn't fix it. Now, what line is it crashing on?

Comment: ok Thanks for your help I've found the reason of why it was crashing !! Forgot to add the "return cell" in the "if let" condition !!